# convert text to decimal(16,2) in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have bytea datatype for file data in my table, I can get file size in MB by using below query in postgres.

```
select concat(length('0x546573742044617461') / 1048576.0)
```

Output of above query is **0.000019073486328125000000** but i want to display **0.00** not whole string, now i want to convert into `decimal(16,2)`

Now I want to display only 2 decimals values.

Example: 
if file size is **1.446119073486328125000000** then output will be **1.45**

if file size is **1.12379073486300** then output will be **1.12**

Equivalent MS-Sql server query is:

```
select CAST(CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),DATALENGTH(0x546573742044617461)/ 1048576.0 ) as decimal(16,2)) as NVARCHAR(50))
```

Could you please help me on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number, then concat() makes no sense. Use `round()` to round the result of the division.

```
select round(length('0x546573742044617461') / 1048576.0, 2)
```